# Print NULL fields from array using implode PHP?

Tags: php

I have a strange problem. I have this piece of code:

```
$array = array('abc',null,'def',null);
$implode = implode(",", $array);
var_dump($implode);
```

and the result is:

```
string 'abc,,def,' (length=9)
```

Is there any way I can print `null` as a string? I mean, some thing like this:

```
string 'abc,null,def,null' (length=17)
```

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:**

Thank you all for your responses. I think they are the same, but developed differently. I was thinking in `array_map` but I didn't know exactly how to use it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `array_walk` to go over every item in the array and turn them to string if they are null:

```
$array = array('abc',null,'def',null);
function x(&$el) {
    $el = ($el === null) ? 'null' : $el;
}
array_walk($array, 'x');
$implode = implode(",", $array);
var_dump($implode);
```

Comment: I was just about to post the same solution. Too fast 4 me ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could map the nulls before.

```
$arrayMapped = array_map(function ($val) { return $val != null ? $val : 'null';}, $array);

$implode = implode(",", $arrayMapped);
```